# Click event occurs more than once

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

When a user clicks the logo, the login form flips. Its functions correctly, but when a user clicks on the login form to enter email and password it flips back to the logo again.

How do I stop the flipping once it has flipped?

html example to understand

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flipWrapper').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.flipWrapper {
    background: none;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flipWrapper .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(180deg);
    background: none;
}
.flipWrapper .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flipWrapper .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
.flipWrapper .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flipWrapper .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipWrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face front">jQuery</div>
        <div class="face back">Script</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flipWrapper').click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('fliped')){
            $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

First you need to find if your element was allready clicked. You do that by checking if class "fliped" was added to it. If it wasn't then add it with `.addClass('classToAdd')` method.

Comment: where i use it in jquery ?

Comment: In your example here: 
 ....
    $('.flipWrapper').click(function () { ..... <- this line. User proper selector. like I answered. $("form :not(input)") is not real proper but it should work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/exLshp0u/ @tehnuty have a look on script it should not flipped

Comment: Yes exactly you are genius Thanks will disturb you again :-) @tehnuty

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same listener for clicks on the back face, so it also flips back.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.front').click(function () {
    $('.flipWrapper').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    return false;
   });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jJhBXD763tRBAkqkXr27?p=preview

This way you are only listening to clicks on the front face.

Comment: Thanks exactly i am looking for something like this.@Patricio Marrone

Answer (score -1):

You can use a conditional to do the animation just once, like:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('fliped')) $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');
```